# Quadric surfaces containing a ribbon

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If $R\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ is a ribbon associated to a line $L\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ with normal bundle $\mathscr{O}_L\cong N_{L/R}\subset N_{L/\mathbb{P}^3}\cong \mathscr{O}_{L}(1)^2$, why is $R$ contained in a $\mathbb{P}^3$ of quadric surfaces with general member smooth?

(reference: last paragraph of page 26 of *Curves of small degree on cubic threefolds*)

Comment: That $R$ is contained in a $\mathbb{P}^3$ of quadrics follows from $h^0(\mathcal{O}_R(2))=6$ (use the exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_L\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_R\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_L\rightarrow  0$), while $h^0(\mathbb{P}^3,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(2))=10$. For proving that a general one is smooth I guess you need a careful analysis: if not, the $\mathbb{P}^3$ must consist of cones with a fixed vertex, probably one can show that the intersection of these cones cannot contain $R$.

Comment: How do you show $h^0(\mathscr{O}_R(2))=6$? I assume you're doing some sort of Riemann Roch for ribbons, but I couldn't find one online.

Comment: No, I am just using the exact sequence I wrote above, plus $h^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2))=3$ and $h^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2))=0$.